# How can I edit inline javascript in html file at runtime?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, script-tag, rapid-prototyping

I'm using the Chrome browser and I'm trying to edit running JavaScript which resides directly in an HTML file (the HTML file is served by an external host). 
I'd like it to be simple like changing HTML/CSS, yes I know JavaScript is different because it is stateful and it cannot be compared to HTML/CSS but still Chrome supports changing external js files, it just doesn't like when you tamper with inline JavaScript.

Possible solutions which I've thought already:

- Greasemonkey / TamperMonkey / Injecting my own at runtime: Won't solve my problems because the script is nested into an anonymous scope and can't be accessed from outside.
- Man in the middle proxy: Not feasible in the long run, and it takes too much to setup just for what I have to do (I'll keep it as last resort).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: *"it takes too much to setup just for what I have to do"* - Exactly what do you have to do?

Comment: Is livereload and/or a gulpfile too big a hassle for you? Honest question. (I know this isn't editing at runtime). You could try [**lighttable**](http://lighttable.com/).

Comment: I'm trying to understand obfuscated code which runs a game so I can write a bot that plays it. The proxy solution is like a last resort.

Comment: Gotta love people that automatically vote to close without writing anything even in the comments.

Comment: @undefined The html file is served by an external host, how can livereload help with that?

Comment: At the time of writing you did not specify it was served by an external host.

Comment: Yes, sorry now it's clearer

Comment: is it possible for you to create codepen or fiddle for this?

Comment: @NagaSaiA what do you mean? Copying html/js/css to jsfiddle and run it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Use a snippet:

[image: Chrome Snippet to Live Edit Drag and Drop Quirksmode inline JavaScript]

**References**

- [Run Snippets Of Code From Any Page  |  Web  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets)
- [5 Useful Chrome DevTools Tips for Developers - Hongkiat](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/chrome-web-developers-tips/)